# Android: how to communicate from worker thread to a service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I've created a service class and a worker class that is executed in a separate thread. I would like to setup a communication between them, so the worker could send some status back to the service.

I've tried to convert my worker `Thread` to `HandlerThread` and setup a `Handler` on the service side, but then I don't know how to actually send a message from the worker. It looks like I can't grasp the concept.

Here's my classes (without communication logic):

#### Service class

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class ConnectionService extends Service {

    protected ConnectionWorker thread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        // Creating a connection worker thread instance.
        // Not starting it yet.
        this.thread = new ConnectionWorker();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Service created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Service started");

        // Checking if worker thread is already running.
        if (!this.thread.isAlive()) {

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Starting working thread");

            // Starting the worker thread.
            this.thread.start();
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Stopping thread");

        // Stopping the thread.
        this.thread.interrupt();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Stopping service");

        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Service destroyed");
    }
}
```

#### Worker class

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;


public class ConnectionWorker extends Thread {

    public ConnectionWorker() {
        super(ConnectionWorker.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        super.run();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Thread started");

        // Doing the work indefinitely.
        while (true) {

            if (this.isInterrupted()) {
                // Terminating this method when thread is interrupted.
                return;
            }

            // @todo: send a message to the service

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Doing some work for 3 seconds...");
            SystemClock.sleep(3 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I implement a `HandlerThread`, send messages from the worker thread and receive them in my service?

I will highly appreciate a code example.

## Update

Actually, it looks like I can't use `Looper` inside of my thread cause it will block the thread execution and I don't want that. Is it possible to send messages from the thread without using `Looper`?

Comment: Could you please give a hint what do you want to do with messages received "in your service". Strictly speaking you can not send messages to your service, you can send messages to a thread looper, in case of your service this will be main thread looper.

Comment: @Okas, thank you for a reply. I'm going to display some status information from the worker in one of the fragments.

Comment: Then you do not want to send messages to service. What you want to do is update ui from background thread, the fact is that this thread was started by a service is not important. Have a look at this example https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: i do not know if you know, but Services run on the thread your activity,fragments,broadcastreceiver,views  runs on, so if you want to update something, use the post(runnable) on a handler and call your update directly there, is it edible enough to you sir?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Elitz. I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to implement this `HandlerThread` correctly. As far as I understood, the `Handler` should be on receiving side, in my case in the service. I can implement it there, but I'm not sure how to actually send the message from the thread to it. An example where thread is communicating with a service will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I've finally nailed it!

In order to pass data from thread back to a service you will need to do this:

1. Subclass a `Handler` class inside of your service (call it e.g. a `LocalHandler`). You will have to make it static. Override a `handleMessage` method, it will receive messages from the thread.
2. Add a `Handler` argument to your `Thread` constructor. Instantiate your `LocalHandler` class in a service and inject it to your thread via constructor.
3. Save reference to the `Handler` inside of your thread and use it to send  messages whenever appropriate.

Here's the complete example:

## Service Class

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;


public class ConnectionService extends Service {

    protected ConnectionWorker thread;

    static class LocalHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Message received: " + (String) msg.obj);
        }
    }
    protected Handler handler;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        // Instantiating overloaded handler.
        this.handler = new LocalHandler();

        // Creating a connection worker thread instance.
        // Not starting it yet.
        // Injecting our handler.
        this.thread = new ConnectionWorker(this.handler);

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Service created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Trying to start the service");

        // Checking if worker thread is already running.
        if (!this.thread.isAlive()) {

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Starting working thread");

            // Starting the worker thread.
            this.thread.start();

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Service started");
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Stopping thread");

        // Stopping the thread.
        this.thread.interrupt();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Stopping service");

        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Service destroyed");
    }
}
```

## Worker Class (Thread)

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;


public class ConnectionWorker extends Thread {

    // Reference to service's handler.
    protected Handler handler;

    public ConnectionWorker(Handler handler) {
        super(ConnectionWorker.class.getName());

        // Saving injected reference.
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        super.run();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Thread started");

        // Doing the work indefinitely.
        while (true) {

            if (this.isInterrupted()) {
                // Terminating this method when thread is interrupted.
                return;
            }

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Doing some work for 3 seconds...");

            // Sending a message back to the service via handler.
            Message message = this.handler.obtainMessage();
            message.obj = "Waiting for 3 seconds";
            this.handler.sendMessage(message);

            SystemClock.sleep(3 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it's a valid implementation. If you now a better approach - please let me know.

Comment: This works. Handlers should be static anyway just forgot that in my rush. Just as a note from your question getExtraType was whatever Type you wanted (int, string, etc.) and to get a context for your thread you would need to pass it as a parameter to the thread constructor. Glad you got it going.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Another thing to note on is you can remove your SystemClock sleep call and do handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); That will wait 3 seconds and then execute the thread which will send your message to your handler without the need to interrupt the system

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to use `postDelayed` instead of `while true` loop? If I remove the loop will it not terminate the thread?

Comment: The while loop is a practice for a thread that you want to loop indefinitely and then stop when explicitly told to. If you want to perform a single task you should look into the AsyncTask class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Slava, actually, your answer doesn't work. Let me explain why.

*Why does Android have HandlerThread when Thread already exists?*

This is because as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) says, HandleThread is a

> Handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper. The looper
>   can then be used to create handler classes. Note that start() must
>   still be called.

*How is a Looper used to create a Handler?*

A Looper should be passed in the Handler's constructor to tell the Handler which Looper it is working with.

So each HandlerThread has one Looper and there can be many Handlers handling messages the Looper loops through.

---

When you created a new Handler in your Service class using the default constructor, the Handler gets associated to the current Looper, as explained in it's documentation.

> Handler ()
>
> Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the
>   current thread. If this thread does not have a looper, this handler
>   won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.

You can confirm the problem still exists using by printing this

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

at appropriate places - within the Service's `onCreate()`, within the Handler's `handleMessage()` and within the `run()` of ConnectionWorker. How to solve your problem then?

You can create a HandlerThread, even within the service, and when it's Looper is ready, create the Handler using that Looper.

```
new HandlerThread("ConnectionWorker") {
    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        new Handler(getLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do your stuff

                getLooper().quitSafely();
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

Hope it isn't too late an answer :P

Comment: Thank you for an elaborate answer, but I was just experimenting with Android a long time ago and I'm not working with it now. So I can't really validate or fully-comprehend your answer. Thank you anyway, I hope it will help someone out there ;)