# thread inside IntentService stop updating Notification

Tags: android, multithreading, android-notifications, android-intentservice, java-threads

i have intentservice associate with geofence. service is called a notification send and inside service their is a thread which update the notification after 10 sec.

here is code:

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
sendNotification("enter",2);
```

`t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {`

```
                                    Thread.sleep(10000);


                                    sendNotification("PICK",2);



                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.e("ERROR",e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        t.start();
```

`}`

here is send notification code

`private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails,String itineraryID) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("ID",ItineraryID);`

```
    // Construct a task stack.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Detail.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Define the notification settings.
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.to_chegando_icon)
            // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
            // to decode the Bitmap.
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.to_chegando_icon))
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle("Saida da Escola"+ itineraryID)
            .setContentText(notificationDetails)
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Issue the notification
    int n=Integer.parseInt(itineraryID);
    mNotificationManager.notify(n, builder.build());
}`
```

this work fine create notification and update it after 10 second.

the problem is when i create a notification and then kill the app from background(press home button and then kill app from background apps)  then this thread doesnot update the notification. why is that ??? any solution

Comment: try to add android:remote in manifest service tag.

Comment: `android:exported="true"` already have this in my service tag and not able to add android:remote

Comment: android:process=":remote" use this in service

Comment: still not able to add it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28926229/6756514

Comment: this link is send data back to service from a thread.
my problem is i have to make a notification from a thread running in a service

Comment: you can try to use Handler, see if it is running even after app clears

Comment: i tried but it also does not not work

Comment: Intent service are not alive, you need to use Service class instead.